# Mann Kendall Test showing significance when it shouldnt

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame in R from 1981 to 2022 with minimum latitudes associated with each year. In this particular data frame, the latitude does not change at all for all 42 years. I run a Mann Kendall on this data but it returns a P value less than 0.05. Am I doing something incorrectly?

```
##     My Code      ###
BF.Min <- as.ts(RangeDF4 %>% filter(Species == "Bluefish") %>% dplyr::select(Year, min) %>% arrange(Year))
MannKendall(BF.Min)                           # significant trend # tau = -0.299, 2-sided pvalue =0.00019187


##   Reproducible code   ##
#dput(BF.Min)
BF.Min <- structure(c(1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 
31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899, 31.399899
), dim = c(42L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Year", "min")), tsp = c(1, 
42, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix", "array"))
MannKendall(BF.Min)
```

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.